# How to update a specific row of a table in Excel using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: excel, rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I try to update a specific row of a table in Excel using Microsoft Graph.

I didn't find any document in [the table section](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/table).

For example, I want to update No. 6 row (index 5).

Is there any way like this? Thanks

```
PATCH:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive/items/12345/workbook/tables/Table1/rows/update

{
  "index": 5,
  "values": [
    [1, 2, 3]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can patch the table row as below. This example updates row 2 (index=1) of a table that contains 4 columns. Note that index value is 0-indexed and also header row is not part of the rows collection here.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/nameditemtest.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/sheet1/tables/Table1/rows/$/ItemAt(index=1)

{
 "values": [
        [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D"
        ]]
}
```

Result: 
[image]

If you wish to patch the header row, you can patch the underlying range `values` property using path of  `PATCH ../tables/{id|name|}/rows/$/ItemAt(index={index}/headerRowRange` -OR- update `name` property of the table column using path of `PATCH ../tables/{id|name}/columns/{id}`

Comment: works perfect! just need update to let people know this

Comment: how do we delete a specific row?

Comment: thank you.  6 years later i was trying for too long to have the row index in the json body like the sparse ms docs still kind of hint at, 6 years later, which i can attest does not work and does not complain either

Comment: The patch URL requires your index after /row as in row/$/ItemAt(index=1) for an index of 1. This info is above in the answer and is critical, but it is extremely easy to miss here on SO due to the box where one must scroll all the way to the right to notice the critical bit of the URL.  So, I am calling it out here in a comment where somebody immediately might see the important bit.